# New users restrictions restrict embedding images but not embedding YouTube videos

Tags: feature-request, new-users, youtube

Have a few representative freehanded circles that will no doubt explain the issue in fully without further need for words.

[image]
[10k-on-Gaming-only link to the above.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73443/are-the-clues-necessary-to-advance-in-the-game/73455#73455)

What? You're so completely disconnected by the collective freehanded-circle mindhive to require words to have meaning conveyed to you? Poor you. Here, let me try and explain with those imperfect tools called words.

As [fbueckert](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/20456/fbueckert) [pointed out](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4881/23) and as you can see, 1 rep users [can't post images, more than two links, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) — and yet bare Youtube links will still expand to the embedded player.

Now this isn't a particularly grave problem as:

- It only works on sites that expand Youtube links to the embedded player ([Arqade, Movies & TV, SciFi, etc.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297500/351462))
- The embedded YouTube player feature is rather hidden

...but it still is most likely a bug rather than a feature.

Comment: I am so embedding Numa Numa 10 hours into all Gaming answers now