# Which sites have YouTube embedding on?

Tags: support, faq-proposed, youtube

*My "home" Stack is* [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com), *where YouTube-embedding is on, which means that a bare YouTube URL on a line by itself is automatically turned into an embedded player. Because of that, I often mistakenly expect it on other Stacks as well, so that I end up posting bare YouTube URLs. Because of this, I'm interested in a list of all Stacks that have this feature turned on.*

---

[According to Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104189/239016), the sites that have YouTube-embedding turned on, are

- Arqade
- Music (but *not* Music Fans)
- SF & Fantasy
- Movies & TV

**Are there any other Stacks that have it turned on?**

Is there a way to find out *automatically*? For instance, similar to the [script to find out which sites have TeX turned on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/239016).

Comment: [Anime.se](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/can-we-have-embedded-youtube-videos-enabled) request is still pending

Comment: It is not in the sites type in the API, nor is it visible or detectable in the page source of a site so that basically rules out doing it automatically. Why do you need this info?

Comment: Pretty sure those four are the only sites supporting YouTube embedding, the team ignored all requests to switch this on other sites, so guess it's final. Jeff might have other plans, but he's long retired from SE so what he said/planned is not relevant. :/

Comment: I have given up but if you fancy running [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/687269?dbmin=101&dbmax=120) for all databases (dbid's> 5 and < 342) you should in the end have a list of sites that once had YT embedding on.

Answer (score 25):

I've put together an incomplete list of sites based on manual testing and site-specific research. (Essentially, searching posts from [every site](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) and [running tests when necessary](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2824/formatting-sandbox/3927#3927))

The majority of the hyperlinks below point to relevant meta discussions about whether YouTube embedding should or should not be allowed on the respective site.

#### Sites which *do* support YouTube embedding

- [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10676/embed-youtube-videos-using-the-html5-player)
- [Aviation](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1736/can-we-turn-on-youtube-video-embedding)
- [Bicycles](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/701/youtube-video-embedding-is-now-enabled)
- [Movies & TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2105/supported-urls-for-video-embedding)
- [Music Fans](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/requesting-automatic-embedding-of-youtube-and-sound-cloud-links)
- [Music Practice & Theory](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled)
- [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2210/could-we-get-youtube-embedding)
- [Space Exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/572/would-it-be-useful-to-be-able-to-put-videos-in-questions-and-answers)
- [Video Production](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled)
- [Sports](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/998/videos-and-questions-on-sports-se)

#### Sites which have *requested* YouTube embedding

- [Anime & Manga](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/can-we-have-embedded-youtube-videos-enabled)
- [Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/can-we-please-be-added-to-the-sites-allowed-to-embed-youtube-videos)
- [Home Improvement](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/572/would-it-be-useful-to-be-able-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-posts)
- [Woodworking](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287/enable-youtube-embeds-for-woodworking)

#### Sites which *do not* support YouTube embedding

- [3D Printing](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226/is-the-inlining-videos-capability-turned-off-on-this-site)
- [Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/formatting-sandbox-please-test-stuff-here/3792#3792)
- [Amateur Radio](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39133267#39133267)
- [Arduino](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2454/does-arduino-support-embedded-youtube-videos)
- [Ask Different](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/can-we-implement-youtube-video-embedding-on-ask-different)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1200/youtube-embedding-request)
- [Blender](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93/should-we-enable-video-embedding)
- [Bioinformatics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39153625#39153625)
- [Bricks](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89/should-video-embedding-be-enabled/164)
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3282/video-player-integration-in-answers)
- [Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13454/does-code-golf-support-embedded-youtube-videos)
- [Computer Graphics](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/do-we-want-youtube-embedding)
- [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3100/allow-youtube-video-embeds)
- [Expats](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/a/323/)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1175/why-cant-we-embed-a-video-in-a-question-or-answer)
- [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1151/could-we-get-embedded-youtube-video)
- [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26270/can-i-embed-a-youtube-video)
- [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/298813#298813)
- [Puzzling](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6036/does-puzzling-support-embedded-youtube-videos/)
- [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here/353869#353869)
- [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4926/c%C3%B3mo-se-puede-embeber-un-video-de-youtube-en-el-sitio)
- [Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3732/can-i-embed-a-youtube-video-in-a-question-or-answer)
- [The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4695/does-the-workplace-support-embedded-youtube-videos)
- [Unix & Linux](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39153625#39153625)
- [User Experience](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/should-we-be-able-to-embed-youtube-videos)
- [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5141/no-youtube-embedded-videos-here)

#### Unknown

- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=YouTube)
- [Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=YouTube)
- [Cryptography](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=YouTube)
- [Database Administrators](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=YouTube)
- [Data Science](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=YouTube)
- [Emacs](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Youtube)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=YouTube)
- [English Language Learners](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=YouTube)
- [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=YouTube)
- [Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/search?q=YouTube)

Comment: I wonder if Jeff's answer should be updated with the first block of information... I, for one, often refer to it as a primary source and if it's out of date, it should be corrected.

Comment: It's still twice as many sites as Jeff's listed... there's no need to be perfectly correct... it's already *more* correct.

Comment: @Catija I've added a comment to his answer linking to the more complete list.

Comment: It should just be enabled on all sites.

Comment: @endolith I’m not sure what use a site like Stack Overflow would have for video embedding.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Linking to a Youtube video that helps answer a programming question

Comment: @endolith You can still link to a YouTube video, it just isn’t embedded in the post

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Why shouldn't it be? Here's an example of where I wanted to embed two videos: https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/14850/10373

Comment: @endolith You could put in a feature request on Meta Politics if you would like to see YT embedding enabled

Comment: @StevenVascellaro It should be enabled on all sites, as I said above

Comment: As far as I can tell, it doesn't work on [skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) either (at least, it didn't appear to embed the video in the preview of my edit).

Comment: @V2Blast YouTube videos don’t embed in the preview window. It only appears after posting

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: Thanks for the heads-up! Tried submitting the edit, but it still just appears as a URL rather than an embedded video, so I suppose now I've confirmed that it doesn't work on skeptics.SE.

Comment: @endolith "It should just be enabled on all sites." Not really, [Stack Overflow didn't like it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397409/thank-you-for-enabling-youtube-embedding).

Comment: @mindstormsboi That doesn't mean it should be disabled