# Allow YouTube /embed URLs to be embedded

Tags: feature-request, youtube

[Certain SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297500/which-sites-have-youtube-embedding-on) allow YouTube videos to be embedded by pasting in the URL. [Testing on the Formatting Sandbox](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3927/48480) shows that SE supports a few different URL types.

Ironically, one URL type that can't be embedded on Stack Exchange are `/embed` URLs.

The advantage of an `/embed` YouTube URL is that it allows for extra parameters, such as setting a [specific end time](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/61397/how-to-share-a-youtube-video-with-a-specific-start-and-end-time). (i.e. [`https://www.youtube.com/embed/BSpAWkQLlgM?start=89&end=108`](https://www.youtube.com/embed/BSpAWkQLlgM?start=89&end=108))

**Would it be possible to support embedding for `/embed` YouTube URLs?**

Comment: More & simpler spams are coming.