# Let me search for embedded Youtube videos

Tags: feature-request, bug, search, youtube

Some sites allow embedded Youtube videos. ([Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297500/323179) is a list of such sites.) However, these videos cannot be found via search.

For example, [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36486/70064) has a broken embedded video with this URL: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtbOmpTnyOc`. Here's what I get when I try to search:

- [`qtbOmpTnyOc`](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=qtbOmpTnyOc): 0 results
- [`url:qtbOmpTnyOc`](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3AqtbOmpTnyOc): 0 results
- [`url:"qtbOmpTnyOc"`](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22qtbOmpTnyOc%22): 1 result (a different post that links to the same broken video)

The results don't change no matter if I use the full URL or surround it with asterisks.

This came up for me because I'm doing stuff with finding broken videos and sometimes it would be more convenient for me to be able to find it with the site search (as opposed to SEDE). If this worked, it would also allow me to search for videos easily across all sites via StackExachange.com search.

---

On a side note, there is a bug here. I should not have to use quotes to find that other result; the search without quotes (second bullet) should also be able to find it.

Comment: I get 500 embedded YouTube video results at Movies & TV with the search term `url:youtube.com/watch`. Interestingly, none of those results include the particular answer in this question. I can find the answer in your third hit if I search on `technique morphed`, but not when using the URL keyword.

Comment: @JasonBassford Don’t you mean **linked** videos? Those I can find no problem. It’s when you can play the video on Stack exchange that there’s a problem.

Comment: I may be using the wrong terminology. I assumed that the text you're looking for appears in the code used to define embedded videos, just as it appears in the code used to define the linked videos—despite not appearing in the body of the text as you view the posts. (I don't have edit rights at that site to test that.) But while your third hit appears for me with `technique morphed`, it does not appear for me with `technique morphed url:youtube.com/watch`, with or without quotation marks. (Even though code-text-only questions and answers do appear for me with that keyword on its own.)