# Is there dedicated video hosting for Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, videos

I know there is a place to upload .blend files for blender.stackexchange, also I heard about Imgur. Is there a similar place for videos?

Comment: No there isn't. We're still primarily text based

Comment: Doesn't youtube do a decent job of video hosting?  I suppose there could be some compression going on to get down to standard sizes.

Comment: @CrossRoads true but with imgur no user can just delete an image. YouTube videos uploaded for SE could be uploaded by any user and any one of them can just decide to remove a video making the link in any question or answer break.

Comment: @CrossRoads you have to create channel, also login not only here but there also. Ask youself what is easier to upload .blend file on blender.stackexchange's hosting or to google drive.

Comment: @Kodos Johnson remove a video from your YouTube channel? I thought only channel owner can do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Videos can be hosted on YouTube for ***inline*** display on your profile, in comments in our chat rooms and certain Stack Exchange sites, such as [video.SE](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/23460/18314), allow YouTube videos in Q&As. An out-of-date [list of sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298854/282094) is available.

Videos hosted elsewhere, such as Vimeo, are not inlined and become an off-site link; so it's possible to have videos that are not on YouTube if you don't want them thumbnailed and embedded in your post.

If you don't want your own YouTube account associated with your Stack Exchange account (and to have comments, possibly voting, over there) you'll need an anonymous YouTube account or to use someone else's video, since it's not the same as including an image in your answer here; where imgur automatically and anonymously (anyone can reuse the link, and whom uploaded it isn't public info) hosts it.

Comment: I think the reason why people prefer dedicated video hosting is because with YouTube users can delete videos willy nilly and cause questions and answers to break.

Comment: @KodosJohnson It's easy to [create an additional channel on YouTube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1646861) and you can [make the link unlisted](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). Only YouTube employees can delete your video, and would only do so for a reason. Most links in answers aren't hosted on the author's own site and subject to link rot; the example link offered clearly described the contents of the video, in the event that it ever goes missing or is unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

If it is really short, you can upload a GIF to Imgur:

[image: an animated GIF of a loading symbol]

They need to be very compressed, but this still can work.

For example, on [this Physics question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/476393/205562), I demonstrated the phenomena I was asking about with a GIF.