# On sites allowing YouTube embeds, allow embedding YouTube Shorts as well as normal YouTube videos

Tags: feature-request, youtube

YouTube launched their new [Shorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube_Shorts) videos in July 2021. However, while the Stack Exchange network does support embedded YouTube videos on [various sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297500/377214), it appears it does not support embedding "Shorts" videos.

If you click the "share" link on such a video, it has the format `https(:)//youtube.com/shorts/j-q366U2Kjs?feature=share`. The "j-q366U2Kjs" part is the same unique identifier each YouTube video has, and thus that URL can actually be rewritten as a regular YouTube URL, either as the "full" URL—`https(:)//www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-q366U2Kjs`—or as the "shortened" URL YouTube provides—`https(:)//youtu.be/j-q366U2Kjs`. These last two are supported by Stack Exchange and are converted into embedded videos, but the "shorts" format isn't.

Would it be possible to update the Stack Exchange software which converts a regular YouTube URL to an embedded video, to also support the "shorts" format? I fear that expecting users to convert the shorts URL into a regular URL themselves is an uphill battle.

Comment: What's next? Embedding TikTok videos? ;)

Comment: Well, considering that some videos that were previously uploaded as normal videos have since been retroactively converted by YouTube to be Shorts, I'm in favor.

Comment: If we go this route, can we please put a reputation threshold on it (20 rep or so, just enough to keep the spammers/trolls out).

Comment: Why would we want suddenly want to allow embedding "Shorts" when everyone has always been profoundly against embedding "Longs"? The *length* isn't the issue. It's the *video* part. No thanks.

Comment: Everyone? Profoundly against? Having the video on the page I'm reading with the question is vastly better than trying to switch between the question and the video, especially when I want to confirm the exact details I'm looking for. Indeed the length is irrelevant, the video part is important, and we should be able to use all of them if we think that any of them are useful.

Comment: @CodyGray (and several others who seemingly did not read the question): **This question is not about allowing YT embeds on all SE sites**. It is about the ***existing*** functionality working properly for a "new" (1.5 year old) format on those sites. YT embeds are regularly used on Movies & TV for instance and we're careful not to have "video only" questions and answers.

Comment: Well seriously now, what's the benefit? That format is meant for kids and TikTok users to post their silly videos and share with friends. Nothing related to SE. I can't see any reason to spend time adding support for this.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars It's likely literally changing one line of code. As for "meant for kids and TikTok users to post their silly videos and share with friends": nope, plenty of proper content creators use these to post short videos. Again: **SE already supports embedded YT videos** and as part of that functionality **supports at least two  different URLs**. All I'm asking is for it to support a third type of URL.

Comment: The pushback you're getting on this seems ridiculous; it's a format change, nothing more. For sites that already have YouTube embeds as a standard part of their community, this change reduces friction for using a site feature, and sounds like a no-brainer addition to me. People who don't use sites where this practice is commonplace need to set aside their preconceived notions and undue criticism of a feature that doesn't even affect their sites in the slightest.

Comment: The video IDs still work in the normal youtube player.  I haven't tried, but I guess it works fine for embedded videos as well.

Comment: @OskarSkog *"I fear that expecting users to convert the shorts URL into a regular URL themselves is an uphill battle."*

Comment: I'd suspect on sites where youtube embeds are needed - there's some situations where a short might be handy. I'm not overfond of the vertical aspect ratio but I vaguely recall youtube changes things to shorts, and there *could* be useful references in that format